# One shot Streams

Tags: node.js

The following will not work properly:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var theIndex = fs.createReadStream('index.html');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    theIndex.pipe(res);
}).listen(9000);
```

It will work great on the first request but for all subsequent requests no index.html will be sent to the client. The createReadStream call seems to need be inside the createServer callback. I think I can conceptualize why, but can you articulate why in words? It seems to be that once the stream has completed the file handle is closed and the stream must be created again? It can't simply be "restarted"? Is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Streams contain internal state that keeps track of the state of the stream--in the case of a file stream, you have [a file descriptor object](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/59dac01e4eaebd01714b6640ae2cd656796147fb/lib/fs.js#L1475), [a read buffer](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/59dac01e4eaebd01714b6640ae2cd656796147fb/lib/fs.js#L1491-1495), and [the current position the file has been read to](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/59dac01e4eaebd01714b6640ae2cd656796147fb/lib/fs.js#L1517-1519). Thus, it doesn't make sense to "rewind" a Node.js stream because Node.js is an asynchronous environment--this is an important point to keep in mind, as it means that two HTTP requests can be in the middle of processing at the same time.

If one HTTP request causes the stream to begin streaming from disk, and midway through the streaming process *another* HTTP request came in, there would be no way to use the same stream in the second HTTP request (the internal record-keeping would incorrectly send the second HTTP response the wrong data). Similarly, rewinding the stream when the second HTTP request is processed would cause the wrong data to be sent to the *original* HTTP request.

If Node.js were *not* an asynchronous environment, and it was guaranteed that the stream was completely used up before you rewound it, it might make sense to be able to rewind a stream (though there are other considerations, such as the timing of the `open`, `end`, and `close` events).

You do have access to the [low-level `fs.read` mechanisms](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback), so you could theoretically create an API that only opened a single file descriptor but spawned multiple streams; each stream would contain its own buffer and read position, but share a file descriptor. Perhaps something like:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var theIndexSpawner = createStreamSpawner('index.html');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    theIndexSpawner.spawnStream().pipe(res);
}).listen(9000);
```

Of course, you'll have to figure out when it's time to close the file descriptor, making sure you don't hold onto it for too long, etc. Unless you find that opening the file multiple times is an actual bottleneck in your application, it's probably not worth the mental overhead.